# ¿Por qué me dice que el codigo está mal?

Tags: javascript

Estoy haciendo varios ejercicios y me quedé bloqueado en éste. La consigna me dice:

> Escribir una funcion que reciba un string (string) y retorne true si encuentra la palabra "bomba" adentro. Si no, retorna false.

Pero cuando ejecuto el código javascript con *git bash* me dice que debería volver el booleano al revés y no como dice la consigna.

¿Dónde estaría mi error?

```js
function encontrarLaBomba(string) {

  // Escribir una funcion que reciba un string (string) y retorne true si encuentra la palabra "bomba" adentro. Si no, retorna false.
  
  // Ej:
  
  // encontrarLaBomba('no hay bomba aqui') => true;

  // encontrarLaBomba('claro que si hay una bom!') => false;

  // Tu código:
  
  if (string === "bomba")
    
    return true;
  
  } else {
    
    return false;
  
  }

}
```

Comment: El código debe ir en formato texto, [no en imagen](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2990/un-fragmento-de-c%c3%b3digo-vale-m%c3%a1s-que-mil-im%c3%a1genes-c%c3%b3mo-sensibilizar-a-los-usu/3976#3976). Por favor corrige eso. Saludos

Comment: Por otro lado, tu función sólo devuelve `true` cuando una cadena es exactamente igual a `"bomba"`, por lo tanto no realiza lo que se pide.

Comment: Perdon por lo del codigo, soy nuevo aca. Y lo otro no lo entendi muy bien perdon, como deberia resolverlo?

Comment: Tienes que buscar dentro del string la palabra "cadena". Mira si hay alguna función para buscar dentro de una cadena otras...(seguro que la ha visto anteriormente en algún tutorial)

Comment: Ya lo resolvi, gracias a todos! En vez de "bomba" iba "no hay bomba aqui"

Comment: ***En vez de "bomba" iba "no hay bomba aqui"***, esa no es la solución, lee la respuesta que dí.

Comment: @MauricioContreras tiene razón. Aunque las pruebas dos pruebas unitarias se cumplan, en realidad no estás cumpliendo la consigna y si hubiera una segunda prueba unitaria que requiriera un `true` tu función fallaría si usas "no hay bomba aqui" como comprobación exacta. El problema está en que te pide que "bomba" esté incluida en la cadena, no que sea exactamente ese el contenido.

Answer (score 4):

Existen diversas formas de realizar la tarea, te presento la siguiente que utiliza el método [`includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/includes) del tipo `String` de Javascript.

El método `includes()` devolverá `true` o `false` en caso de que la cadena pasada como argumento se encuentre dentro de la cadena que estamos analizando.

Podrías devolver directamente el resultado de esta función y estarías cumpliendo con lo que se te pide en el ejercicio:

```js
function encontrarLaBomba(string) {
  // Escribir una funcion que reciba un string (string) y retorne true si encuentra la palabra "bomba" adentro. Si no, retorna false.
  // Ej:
  
  // encontrarLaBomba('no hay bomba aqui') => true;

  // encontrarLaBomba('claro que si hay una bom!') => false;
  return string.includes('bomba');
}

console.log(encontrarLaBomba('no hay bomba aqui')); // true

console.log(encontrarLaBomba('claro que si hay una bom!')); // false
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
```

El error en tu código es que estás simplemente comparando la cadena recibida con la cadena `"bomba"`, por lo tanto siempre devolverá `false` a menos que la cadena introducida sea exactamente igual a `"bomba"`.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias por tu tiempo, de enserio! Tengo otras dudas pero puedo publicar cada 40 minutos, podria contactarte por algun lado si es posible? Gracias!

Comment: Claro, puedes entrar al [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30872/stack-overflow-en-espanol) de [es.so], @BrianAcuña